# How to call activity of one project from activity of another project in android?Also vice versa?

Tags: android

I am doing an integration project,which involves integrating two projects into one.How I want to do this is,I have a common project,the activity of this common project should be able to call activities of the other two projects,as per different events like a particular button press,etc.How can I do this?Is it possible through intents?

Also,the activities of the other two projects should be able to call each other.How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

this Android Developer blog post explains how to make custom application intents available to other applications for this sort of integration:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/11/integrating-application-with-intents.html

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use intent filters, Sample code below

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    Intent baseIntent = new Intent(ACTION_PICK_PLUGIN);
    baseIntent.addCategory("matching.catagory");

    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(baseIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

Then fire intent using the following,

```
Intent baseIntent = new Intent(activities.get(indexOfChild).filter.getAction(0));
baseIntent.addCategory(activities.get(indexOfChild).filter.getCategory(0));     
baseIntent.setComponent(newComponentName(activities.get(indexOfChild).activityInfo.packageName,activities.get(indexOfChild).activityInfo.name));
startActivity(baseIntent);
```

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the MainActivity of a project from the existing project and vice versa you can use PackageManager class

```
        Intent i;
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        try {
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("Target package");
            if (i == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            i.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        }
```