# Call activity from another project

Tags: android, class, android-intent, android-activity, project

i want call project A to project B, but in project B used project C for library.

I used the code in project A

```
intent = new Intent("com.example.projectb.reading");
        startActivity(intent);
```

and AndroidManifest in project B

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.example.projectb.reading" 
        android:label="Trainee" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xample.projecta.cls_show" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but i've got logcat is

```
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835): Process: com.xample.projecta, PID: 7835
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xample.projecta/com.xample.projecta.show}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030033
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2435)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:776)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:435)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:176)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:646)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030033
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2345)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3927)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2161)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:413)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at id.co.ajsmsig.eagency.Cls_training.onCreate(cls_show.java:12)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
08-14 15:05:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(7835):     ... 17 more
08-14 15:05:26.691: I/Process(7835): Sending signal. PID: 7835 SIG: 9
```

Please help me, where's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Refer these two links from stackoverflow. It will help you

1. [How to call activity of one project from activity of another project in android?Also vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738624/how-to-call-activity-of-one-project-from-activity-of-another-project-in-android)

2.
[How to call an activity in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596999/how-to-call-an-activity-in-another-project)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
   intent = new Intent("com.example.projectb.reading");
    startActivity(intent);
```

into

```
    intent = new Intent("com.xample.projecta.cls_show");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: com.xample.projecta.cls_show is package name of project A.and the intent used in project A.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong Constructor

```
intent = new Intent(this, "com.example.projectb.reading");
        startActivity(intent);
```

read [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by `Intent-filter`.

**FirstActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.secondapp.SecondActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondActivity - AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.secondapp.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.secondapp.SecondActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For more reference you can refer [this.](http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-of-another-application/)

Comment: You have to change your intent filter's action name as your `Activity` namespace. @user2901572